# Mysql query for fetching videos posted by friends of a particular user

Tags: mysql

Could anyone please help me to write a query in mysql to fetch the videos posted by friends of a particular user. I have 3 tables (users,friends and videos) and the table structure are as follows.

---

users - id

---

friends - id, user_id [from user table], friend_id [from user table]

---

videos - id, user_id [from user table], video_name

---

For ex: User with id 1 has 3 friends 2,3,and 4 mapped in friends table. Each friends has posted 2 videos, mapped in videos table. So when I login as user 1, i need to list the videos posted by 2,3 and 4 with their details fetched from user table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` is what you are looking for. This can be used to "link" multiple tables based on what is common between them. This is the backbone of *Normalization*

The first part will be to link the "Friends" table back to the "Users" table. I am going to use a local variable (@UserID) and set it to be yours. I really don't know what information you will want from the friends information, so I am going to use generics for last name and first name in all of the queries

```
SET @UserID = 1 -- Your UserID

SELECT     u.LastName, u.FirstName
FROM       Friends    AS f
INNER JOIN Users      AS u ON f.Friends_ID = u.User_ID
WHERE     f.User_ID = @UserID
```

Then the second part is going to be linking the Users to the videos. This query will return the user name information along with the names of all the videos:

```
SELECT     u.LastName, u.FirstName, v.video_name
FROM       Users   AS u
INNER JOIN Videos  AS v ON u.User_ID = v.User_ID
```

So now we have the basics. For your example you want a user to get all of the videos from all of their friends. We can actually combine these 2 queries into one query to get this:

```
SET @UserID = 1 -- Your UserID

SELECT     u.LastName, u.FirstName, v.video_name
FROM       Friends  AS f
INNER JOIN Users    AS u ON f.Friends_ID = u.User_ID
INNER JOIN Videos   AS v ON u.User_ID = v.User_ID
WHERE    f.User_ID = @UserID
```